# ManyToMany query

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine, symfony-3.3

I'm trying to execute a many to many query.

This MySQL query gives me exactly what I want:

```
select * from service_offer 
left join service on service.id_service = service_offer.id_service
left join user on user.id_user = service_offer.id_user
```

How do I have to do with Symfony?

I tried something like:

```
public function findAllServiceOffers(){
    $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
        'SELECT s, u FROM AppBundle:Service s
        INNER JOIN AppBundle:User u'
    );

    try {
        return $query->getResult();
    } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

But I get that error:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col -1: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_WITH, got end of string.

If I add a WHERE or WITH clause, the query executes, but I have NULLs values...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to give you two examples quickly:

```
//use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

/** @var Connection $conn */
$conn = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection();
$aResults = $conn->executeQuery($sql)->fetchAll();
```

OR

```
//use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;

/** @var Connection $conn */
$conn = $this->getDoctrine()->getConnection();
$query = $conn->createQueryBuilder()->select('fields')->from('table1','alias_table1');
$query->leftJoin('alias_table1','table2','alias_table2','alias_table1.ID = alias_table2.ID');
$aResults = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

OR

```
//use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
/** @var EntityManager $em */
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$sSQL = $em->createQuery("SELECT t1,t2 FROM YourBundle:Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN t1.fieldOfEntityDoctrine t2 WHERE t2.ID = 'example'")->getSQL();
```

Comment: Thanks! But I don't wanna use the table "service_offer" which is the relation between Service and User. I should be able to user only Service and User, isn't it?

Comment: Sorry, but what would be the relation (without the table **service_offer**)?

Comment: The table service_offer exists and does the relation between service and user. But in Symfony, I shouldnt have to mention this service_offer table. Or? Doctrine should be able to find this table with the annotations I did...